# Composite design pattern with java.util.Map#putAll(Map)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am going through Composite design pattern and found that java.util.Map#putAll(Map) is mentioned as [example](https://dzone.com/articles/composite-design-pattern-java-0) for composite pattern in JDK.I am not able to understand how it follows composite pattern. 
I have few questions about it as below.

> 1. How putAll(map) is composite pattern?
> 2. How part-whole relationship is defined when using putAll?

Can anyone please help me to understand it.

Comment: Wow, that source about the composite pattern is *so* bad. You should read Wikipedia instead.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks for the input.I read wiki but did not find JDK example and when I read example mentioned in question,  got more confused :(

Comment: Composite pattern means that there is some `thing1` that does `action1`, and also there is some other `thing2` that does `action2`. Then, there should be a third `thing3` entirely that does `action3`, and it does that action as some combination of `action1` and `action2`. Do achieve that, `thing3` has a `thing1` and `thing2` as part of itself. To rephrase, `thing3` is **composed** out of `thing1` and `thing2`.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not able to understand how it follows composite pattern.

Don't worry, that's just because it **isn't** an example of composite pattern.

`java.util.Map#putAll(Map m)` mutates `Map this` to add all of the other `Map m`'s elements inside it. After that, the two maps have no parent-child relationship.

If it composed them, then this test would pass:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> child = new HashMap<>();
map.putAll(child); // "Compose" map and child according to article author
child.put("A", "1"); // modify child
assertEquals("1", map.get("A")); // Fails, map is not composed of child
```

I've used `HashMap` there, but all Java implementations of `Map` will work that way, and so should any sane `Map` implementation. You could write your own `Map` implementation to make this `putAll` operation Compose, but it would be violating [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) and a [source of astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).